Negative current flow contradiction?
Does negative current mean the flow of negative charges? If so where do the positive charges from I_1 and I_3 go after reaching the blue node on the image below? I do not understand how the positive and negative charges move through the blue node.


The sooner you forget everything about flow of charges, the sooner you'll understand electricity. When discussing electrical circuits, only think in terms of current. You will never ever have to consider flow of charges. Only those who design battery cells or new semiconductor materials need to think of flow of charges. You and I don't.

You made two errors:

your KCL equation did not conform with arrow direction.

The sign of one or more of the amounts did not conform with arrow direction, leading to a situation which is physically impossible.


I'll describe these errors in detail in a moment, but first let me remind you of some things about current.
Confusion can arise when considering electrons moving, because conventionally we pretend that charges are positive, and always move towards a point with lower potential (voltage). That convention is in keeping with ideas we are familiar with, such as things with positive mass falling in a gravity field; they never fall upwards.
Electrons, having negative charge, actually do fall upwards in an electric field, since the force on them is in the opposite direction. We aren't familiar with this behaviour day-to-day, because we never see objects with negative mass "falling upwards", but that doesn't mean it isn't possible. Negative electric charges (such as electrons) that find themselves in an electric field will "fall" upwards towards the higher potential (voltage), and positive charges in that same field would fall downwards, towards the lower potential, but those two scenarios are indistinguishable physically  and algebraically, at least as far as an engineer or mathematician is concerned.
It doesn't matter what sign the charge has, because the effect on the environment of a negative charge flowing one way is identical to the effect of a positive charge flowing the other way. If you flip the sign of the charge, then you also flip its direction of travel, and you end up with the same physical consequences and the same algebraic results. We therefore always treat current as if it consisted of positive charges moving (falling) towards a lower potential, even though in most cases it's actually electrons moving in the opposite direction.
That brings us to your circuit. :

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The arrows always represent conventional current, meaning that we disregard the fact that it may be electrons moving. If the annotated amount is positive, the arrow tells us the direction of motion of positive charges. If the amount is negative, we assume positive charges moving in a direction opposing the arrow.
\$I_1\$ is positive, which implies positive charges moving in the direction of the arrow, to the right. \$I_3\$ is also positive, implying positive charges moving with the arrow, to the left. Lastly, \$I_2\$ is negative, which means that positive charges are moving against the direction of the arrow, upwards.
That's clearly an impossible situation, since you have all charges entering the junction, which would accumulate there in violation of Kirchhoff's current law. Therefore, this system cannot possibly exist in real life.
Either of the following are possible:

simulate this circuit
On the left I've changed the sign of \$I_2\$. On the right I've changed the direction of \$I_2\$. Both are describing the exact same condition, in which \$I_2\$ consists of positive charges moving downwards, and that means that the sum of all charges entering the junction equals the sum of all charges leaving, in accordance with Kirchhoff's Current Law, which can now be correctly written.
For the left circuit, you would use arrow directions to see that \$I_1\$ and \$I_3\$ are entering the junction, while \$I_2\$ is leaving it. Intuitively you can state that the sum of currents entering must equal the sum of current leaving, and apply KCL in that very form:
$$ I_1 + I_3 = I_2 $$
For the circuit on the right, all currents are entering the junction, which is more in keeping with the classic KCL statement "the sum of all currents entering a junction must be zero". We can therefore write the KCL equation in that spirit:
$$ I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 0 $$
Even though those two circuits are describing the exact same physical scenario, the KCL equations for each is subtly different. To be correct:

Application of KCL must be consistent with the annotated arrow direction.

The sign of the current amount must be consistent with arrow direction.


You violated both of those conditions.
